# is it correct or safe to manualy set the document value of collections in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

by default the document value of collections is generated automatically, how about if we set that manually during insertion? is it safe and a right way?

example:

```
await _firestore.collection('collectionName').document(manualID).setData({...});
```

by this way, I think it is easy to retrieve a specific document from a collection.

Comment: Depends, Say: if you are creating some documents related to a user you may want to set document name to user_id this will make you query data much easier. And if you are creating a document for a post or product you can get away with firestore random ID.

Comment: yes, right now it is related to users.

Comment: @hekmat if the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful thank you!

Comment: @PeterHaddad sure, and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add your own id or you can let firebase generate the id. If you can be sure that each document you will create under the collection will have a different id, then there will be no problem if you add your own implementation.

Firebase generating an id:

```
final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
await firestoreInstance.collection("users").add({});
```

---

Adding your own id:

```
final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
await firestoreInstance.collection("collectionName").document(id).setData({});
```